# How do I create a macro, using Bottle's SimpleTemplate engine, that will be available in several templates?

Tags: python, templates, bottle

I need to format a link in certain places of my Bottle application. Previously all of the links were in one SimpleTemplate file, and I defined a macro that looks like this:

```
%def mylink(obj):
    <a class="mylink" href="{{ get_url('view', id=obj.id) }}">{{ obj.title }}</a>
%end
```

Wherever I needed to format a link to an `obj`, I used:

```
%mylink(some_obj)
```

Now I need to use format such links in several templates. I moved the template definition to a separate file called `macros.html`, then tried `%include`ing this file into the templates where I need the macro:

```
<!-- macros.html -->
%def mylink(obj):
    <a class="mylink" href="{{ get_url('view', id=obj.id) }}">{{ obj.title }}</a>
%end

<!-- somepage.html -->
%include macros
...
%mylink(some_obj)
...
```

However, Bottle cannot resolve the name `mylink` in such a layout.

I understand I can do this:

```
<!-- mylink.html -->
<a class="mylink" href="{{ get_url('view', id=obj.id) }}">{{ obj.title }}</a>

<!-- somepage.html -->
...
%include mylink obj=some_obj
...
```

However, I'm reluctant to do this, as I feel this isn't very fast (I have many links to format on any given page).

Am I missing some other options?

Answer (score 0):

The `%include` statement renderes the included template immediately.

Myby you can solve this using the `%rebase` command, putting your macro into the base template.